# In what sense is $\breve{g}(x-y)/(2\pi)^n$ the integral kernel of $g(-i\nabla)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, distribution-theory, trace, quantum-mechanics

It is said in *Trace Ideals and Their Applications* by Barry Simon that the integral kernel of the operator $g(-i\nabla)$ on $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ is given by $\breve{g}(x-y)/(2\pi)^n$.

Indeed, for any $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$, $$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n_y}\breve{g}(x-y)\psi(y)dy=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n_y}\int_{\mathbb R^n_k}g(k)e^{ik\cdot (x-y)}\psi(y)dkdy=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n_y}\int_{\mathbb R^n_k}g(i\nabla)_ye^{ik\cdot (x-y)}\psi(y)dkdy.$$

Then integration by parts in $y$ gives $$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n_y}\int_{\mathbb R^n_k}g(i\nabla)_ye^{ik\cdot (x-y)}\psi(y)dkdy$$

$$=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n_y}\Big(\int_{\mathbb R^n_k}e^{ik\cdot (x-y)}dk\Big)g(-i\nabla)\psi(y)dy.$$

Now this is the bit I am confused about. Why are we allowed to use $$\int_{\mathbb R^n_k}e^{ik\cdot (x-y)}dk=(2\pi)^n\delta(x=y).$$ If we can use this, then $$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n_y}\Big(\int_{\mathbb R^n_k}e^{ik\cdot (x-y)}dk\Big)g(-i\nabla)\psi(y)dy=\int_{\mathbb R^n_y}\delta(y=x)g(-i\nabla)\psi(y)dy=g(-i\nabla)\psi(x)$$ which shows that $\breve{g}(x-y)/(2\pi)^n$ is the integral kernel of $g(-i\nabla)$.

This is true in the sense of distributions, but it would be great if someone could clarify exactly what sense this is true on $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. What do you mean that "This is true in the sense of distribution...what sense this is true on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$". First, question: what is your definition of $g(-i\nabla)$, i.e. how does $g(-i\nabla)$ acts on Schwartz functions?

Comment: @JackyChong $g$ can be any function, say $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. Indeed, I agree, if $g(-i\nabla)\psi$ is a Schwartz function, then we would indeed have $$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n_y}\Big(\int_{\mathbb R_k^n}e^{ik\cdot(x-y)}dk\Big)g(-i\nabla)\psi(y)dy=\int_{\mathbb R^n_y}\delta(y=x)g(-i\nabla)\psi(y)dy=g(-i\nabla)\psi(x),$$which is what we want. But why can we say this is true in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ (for almost every $x\in\mathbb R^n$)?

Comment: In general, if a linear operator $T:D\subset H\rightarrow H$ is defined on a dense subset say $D\subset H$ and that there exists a $C>0$ such that $\|T(f)\| \le C\|f\|$ for all $f \in D$, then you can extend the linear operator to a bounded operator on all of $H$.

Comment: To not confuse things, you should fix $g$ to be some smooth and compactly supported function (i.e. don't vary $g$ in the expression $g(-i\nabla)$. This is a fixed operator). Then understand your computation.

Answer (score 1):

I will use a slightly different convention of Fourier transform than the one given in Simon's book. It offers you an opportunity to work out the details again as an exercise with Simon's convention.

Here we use the following definition of Fourier transform
\begin{align}
\hat f(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-2\pi i\, \xi\cdot x} f(x)\, dx
\end{align}
and write its inverse transform by $f^{\vee}$. In particular, we have that if $D = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\nabla$, then $\widehat{D f} = \xi\, \hat f$.

By definition, $g(D)$ is defined on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ as follows
\begin{align}
(g(D) f)(x):= \left(g(\xi) \hat f(\xi)\right)^\vee = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i\, \xi\cdot x} g(\xi) \hat f(\xi)\, d\xi.
\end{align}
(If you look carefully at what you have written, you haven't really defined what $g(D)$ actually means.)

Notice that this definition only make sense on a dense subset of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ since Fourier transform using integral is only defined for $L^1$ function. Anyhow, so if you restrict yourselves to $f$ being a Schwartz function, then we see that
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i\, \xi\cdot x} g(\xi) \hat f(\xi)\, d\xi =&\, \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i\, \xi\cdot x} g(\xi) \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{-2\pi i\, y\cdot \xi}f(y)\, dy\right)d\xi\\
=&\, \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{-2\pi i\, (y-x)\cdot \xi}g(\xi)\ d\xi\right)f(y)\, d y\\
=&\, \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g^\vee (x-y)f(y)\, d y
\end{align}
which is the desired result.

**Additional:** To answer the other question in the comment, let us consider the operator $A = h(x)g(-i\nabla)$.

First, we need to understand how $A$ is defined. Well, it should be clear that
\begin{align}
(A f)(x) := h(x) (g(-i\nabla) f)(x)
\end{align}
i.e. apply the operator $g(-i\nabla)$ then apply the multiplication operator $h(x)$.

As above, we see that
\begin{align}
(g(-i\nabla) f)(x)= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g^\vee(x-y) f(y)\, dy
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
(A f)(x) =&\, h(x)\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g^\vee(x-y) f(y)\, dy\\
=&\, \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \underbrace{h(x)g^\vee(x-y)}_{k(x, y)} f(y)\, dy.
\end{align}
As pointed out by you, that the kernel should be
\begin{align}
k(x, y) = h(x)g^\vee(x-y).
\end{align}

Now, let us address your question, "what sense would $h(x)g^\vee(x-y)$ be the integral kernel for $A$?"

First, the theorem that you are quoting is telling you when $A$ a Hilbert--Schmidt operator. Of course, you can not expect every $h(x)g(-i\nabla)$ to be Hilbert--Schmidt. For instance $h(x)g(-i\nabla) = -x\, \Delta$ which is clearly unbounded therefore can't possibly be a compact operator (Hilbert--Schmidt are compact operators). Nevertheless, you could write out its integral kernel
\begin{align}
 -x\, \Delta f =&\,  -x \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Delta_x \delta(x-y) f(y)\, dy \\
=&\, -x \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Delta_x \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{2\pi i (x-y)\cdot\xi}\, d\xi\right) f(y)\, d y\\
=&\, -x \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \underbrace{\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{2\pi i (x-y)\cdot\xi}\underbrace{(-4\pi^2|\xi|^2)}_{g(\xi)}\, d\xi\right)}_{g^\vee(x-y)} f(y)\, d y.
\end{align}

The point of this example is to show you that $g$ doesn't even have to be integrable. Of course, what this means is that the Fourier (or inverse Fourier) transform of $g$ is defined rigorously in the sense of Fourier transform of tempered distributions.

Back to the theorem:  $A$ is a Hilbert--Schmidt operator if and only if $h, g$ are $L^2$ integrable functions.

Hence $A=-x\Delta$ is not a Hilbert--Schmidt operator but
\begin{align}
A:= \frac{1}{(1+|x|)^{d+2}}\frac{1}{(1+|-i\nabla|)^{d+2}}
\end{align}
is a Hilbert--Schmidt operator.

Comment: I am still a little confused. Consider the integral kernel of $A=h(x)g(-i\nabla)$. By a theorem in Barry Simon's Trace Ideals text book, $A$ is Hilbert--Schmidt if and only if $h$ and $g$ are in $L^2$. This implies that an integral kernel in $L^2$ must exist. So in what sense would $h(x)\breve g(x-y)/(2\pi)^{d/2}$ be the integral kernel for $A$? Do we have to write "If additionally $g\in L^1$, then $A$ acts on Schwartz functions in $L^2$ with integral kernel $h(x)\breve g(x-y)/(2\pi)^{d/2}$"?

Comment: @schrodingerscat Let us first figure out what is the main question that you are trying to ask. In the post, I believe you are essentially asking how is $g^\vee(x-y)/(2\pi)^n$ the integral kernel of $g(-i\nabla)$. Okay, to answer your question, I asked in the comment "what is your definition of $g(-i\nabla)$, i.e. how does $g(-i\nabla)$ acts on Schwartz functions?" The point of the question is to see whether you understand what $g(-i\nabla)$ is. Well, since $g(-i\nabla)$ is an operator, then the question is essentially asking whether you know how $g(-i\nabla)$ acts on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: However, I believe your response in the comment didn't quite answer my question. So, I wrote the post by defining how $g(-i\nabla)$ acts on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (in fact, I only defined it on a dense subset of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, just like how one can define a continuous function on the rational then extend by density to a continuous function on the real provided the function is uniformly continuous, not important for our discussion). Once we know how $g(-i \nabla)$ is defined then it is only basic algebraic manipulation to show that the kernel of $g(-i \nabla)$ is the desired quantity.

Comment: Up to this point, I believe this should answer your question about how $g^\vee(x-y)/(2\pi)^n$ is the kernel of $g(-i\nabla)$.

Comment: Now, you are asking about the operator $A=h(x)g(-i\nabla)$. You want to know what is the integral kernel of $A$ right? I have added to the post to answer this second question.